# What happens in a define with empty parentheses? ex: #define FOO ()?

Tags: c++, syntax, branch, c-preprocessor

Put it simply, in my C++ knowledge (or lack of) FOO will be substituted with what is in parenthesis when this was defined. But what happens if the parenthesis are empty? Is it  equivalent to 0? That means a `#ifdef foo (0)` will do the same thing as `#ifdef foo ( )`? If equivalent is any useful effect to be used with empty parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A macro expansion will just expand to whatever the macro is expanded to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define L (
#define R )
#define l {
#define r }
#define LR ()

int main LR
l 
   printf L "Hello, World\n" R;
   return 0;
r
```

would compile perfectly fine (and if you hid the L/R/l/r macros in a header file, nobody would understand what you'd done. Note that spaces are needed at least in some places to ensure the macro actually expands.

This statement

```
 #ifdef CRAPFOO ()
```

won't compile cleanly ("extra tokens at the end of #ifdef" in gcc, other compilers may give other errors.

```
 #define CRAPFOO ()
 #ifdef CRAPFOO
    do something
 #else
    not something
 #endif
```

will give `do something` as the result.

Comment: Petersson you are the man o the year. Thanks for the example. Also you anticipated a problem that got me here, to ask this question, and you answered also what happens. So yes, gcc throws errors at this define. And also I did not understand what branch it will get into.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is an absolutely dumb textual replacement. So:

```
#define FOO ()

int main()
{
    FOO;
}
```

becomes

```
int main()
{
    ();
}
```

You can test this with the `-E` option to `g++` (and I think `clang` too), which means "just do preprocessing", or equivalently, just run the `cpp` tool, which is the c preprocessor.
i.e.

```
$ echo -e "#define FOO ()\nint main()\n{\n    FOO;\n}" > def.cpp ; g++ -E def.cpp 
# 1 "def.cpp"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "def.cpp"

int main()
{
    ();
}
```

(These are the Linux/other Unix command line tools).

Comment: Note the difference between `#define FOO ()` and `#define FOO()`.  I don't think I've ever seen `#define FOO ()`, but `#define FOO()` is frequent.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is a preprocessor directive and is just a stupid text replacement rule which happens *before* actually compiling your code. There's no code model yet when applying the macro definitions.

```
#define FOO ()
```

replaces every occurrence of `FOO` with `()`.

```
#define FOO (0)
```

replaces every occurrence of `FOO` with `(0)`.

```
#define FOO 0
```

replaces every occurrence of `FOO` with `0`, which is **not** the same as `(0)` (there are cases in which this makes a difference).

However,

```
#define FOO()
```

replaces `FOO()` with nothing, doesn't touch `FOO`